# Программа п1 будет принимать данные вызывать п2 передавать эти данные п2 и её результат возвращать

Tags: компилятор, перекодировка, c++, функции

Складывается ощущение что вопрос трудно (или не охота) весь прочитать так что скажу вкратце: как можно перед компиляцией в IDE файла .cpp с utf-8 переделать его в кодировку windows-866 (консоли виндовс) а только потом скомпилировать?

---

Проблема такая: я недавно начал учить C++ у меня Code::Blocks IDE (я использую файлы в UTF-8) и понял что если компилировать файл GNU GCC compiller (он мне нужен т.к. он поддерживает C++ 11) то он оставляет все строковые константы (определённые в файле) абсолютно такими же а в консоли кодировка windows-866 (cmd->chcp подсказала) и получаются крякозябры при выводе этих констант.
Я пытался создать 3 текстовых файла 1й-utf8 2й-ascii 3й-866 (создан в cmd->edit)и просматривать их через C::B::Hex_Editor во всех напечатал:
`ABC123 АБВГДЕЖЗИКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЬЭЮЯЁЙабвгдежзиклмнопрстуфхцчшщъьэюяёй`
Вот результат:
UTF-8:
[image: UTF-8]
Windows-1251:
[image: Windows-1251]
Windows-866:
[image: Windows-866]

Вот такие компиляторы:
[image: Compiler settings]
[image: Advanced compiler options]

Как видно UTF-8 вообще 2х байтовая её понимание и реализация нижеизложенного  (для меня) сложна а вот между 1251 и 866 разница только в числах (байтах) представляющих символы но если возможно прошу помочь с UTF-8 => Windows-866 вариантом ниже изложенного.
Собственно что я придумал (но сам не могу реализовать прошу вас помочь):
Создать программу  (rusmingw32-g++.exe) которую потом в настройках указать как C++ compiler  поместить её туда где и оригинал и:

1) всё что IDE передаёт нашей (rusmingw32-g++.exe) программе сохранять
 2) искать переданный для компиляции файл (filename.cpp) создать filename_rus.cpp в том же каталоге где и оригинал но:
 3) перекодировать filename_rus.cpp из windows1251 (а если можно из UTF-8) в  windows-866
 4) вызвать mingw32-g++ передав ей то что было передано rusmingw32-g++ только вместо filename.cpp подставить filename_rus.cpp
 5) возвратить из нашей (rusmingw32-g++.exe) то что возвратила  (mingw32-g++.exe) вызванная программа

из скриншота с Advanced compiler options вроде видно как вызывается mingw32-g++.exe но я не уверен. Ещё я не уверен что mingw32-g++.exe возвращает всё сразу, мне кажется (судя по бывшей моей IDE Dev C++ которая показывала сколько % завершено) что она возвращает несколько раз через определённые промежутки времени. Помогите реализовать описанную выше (rusmingw32-g++.exe) программу пусть хотя бы принимает файл (filename.cpp) в windows-1251 а если возможно реализовать то в UTF-8. И (если возможно) чтобы (rusmingw32-g++.exe) наша программа возвращала как только ей вызванная (mingw32-g++.exe) что то возвратит.

***PS:*** как я понял межу windows-1251 и windows-866 разница такая:

```
с 0xC0 (192) [А] по 0xEF (239) [о] разница -0x40 (-64)  
с 0xF0 (240) [р] по 0xFF (256) [я] разница -0x10 (-16)
```

помогите сделать что то типа препроцессора описанного выше (это не "работа за автора" а "просьба помочь" ведь используя C++ нормально [с возможностью не думать о русских символах в C++] я освою его и помогу другим)

***PPS:*** перенёс основной вопрос [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198070/c-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%83-cout).

Comment: Перекодировку можно делать с помощья iconv, а все операции вполне нормально расписываются в Makefile (который обрабатывается программой make, служащей для отслеживания и актуализации зависимостей).

Comment: @alexlz а как мне контроллируя make или используя iconv сделать перекодировку? можно for dummies?:)

Comment: Я не знаю этих IDE'в, поэтому мне трудно ориентироваться. Надеюсь другие подскажут. Вот, как пример, правило компиляции (получение .o из .c) с предварительной перекодировкой из cp1251 в utf-8 (кстати, utf-8 -- не двухбайтная, это частный случай):

     TEMPF=$(shell echo $$PPID)
     %.o : %.c
 iconv -f cp1251 -t utf-8 $< >$(TEMPF).c
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TEMPF).c -o $@
 rm $(TEMPF).c

сначала присваивается значение переменной TEMPF -- ppid нового шелла для создания временного файла. Затем -- перекодировка (iconv), трансляция ($(CC)) и удаление (rm). Сборки тут нет.

Comment: А это что для .bat или это для *nix у меня windows и и только начал учить C++ подскажите как использовать предложенный вами код? Это ведь не код на C/C++!?

Comment: Нет. Это кусок Makefile -- исходного файла утилиты make (она часто используется для трансляции-сборки приложений). Точнее даже не просто make, а gnu make. Но, как я уже писал, Ваших картинок я несколько боюсь, надеюсь подскажет кто-нибудь другой, который с ide общался больше, чем я.

Comment: Для начала, по моему мнению, все строки должны быть в Unicode. Если вы прочитали строку в однобайтной кодировке из файла -- не возвращаясь из функции переведите её в Unicode. То же при выводе **в** файл. Все проблемы должны исчезнуть раз и навсегда.

Comment: @Rules, а зачем (на самом-то деле) Вам cp866?

Думаю для того, чтобы программа, запущенная в *стандартной* консоли виндоус печатала русские буквы, а не кракозябры.

Вот и решайте именно задачу правильного (в зависимости от контекста) вывода, а не перекодировки констант (строк символов) внутри исходников программы. 

Лучше продумайте, как определить, что вывод будет в консоль с кодировкой cp866 и перекодировать выводимые символы из кодировки исходника программы в нужную.

Кстати, при переадресации вывода в виндовый файл (ведь просто a.exe > outfile) кодировка должна стать cp1251.

Comment: @avp: помогите реализовать перегрузку << в cout чтобы он изменял свой операнд...

Comment: @Rules, не люблю кресты вообще, а перегрузку, наследование и т.п. тем более.

Если хотите ООП, то возьмите Java, а на низком уровне пишите на Си.

Comment: @avp настоящиие ооперы java за язык не считают. Только язык "трёп (smalltalk)" выдержит проверку на идеологичесукую чистоту.

Comment: @avp а мне кажется что с Java будет много (хотябы в том что JVM нужна) трудностей. И Java ведь сейчас не так популярна как C++? И для Java нет чего то типа MS Visual Studio да?

Comment: @Rules, я не пользуюсь MS Visual Studuio, да и вообще в винде практически не пишу. В линуксе для Си IDE тоже не использую.

Для Java есть [несколько IDE](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_IDE#Java) для разных ОС.

Answer (score 1):

Код C++

```
// установить вручную шрифт Lucida Console в свойствах окна консоли 
// и запомнить это для всех окон с этим именем
// записать в начале программы строку 
 #include <windows.h>
// записать в начале функции main ( после строки с символом { ) 
// две следующих строки 
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Проверено, работает в Code::Blocks IDE.