# Как перегрузить оператор << у cout?

Tags: операторы, перекодировка, c++, библиотеки

В связи с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/196880/c-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF1-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF2-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D1%91-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) вопросом решил задать другой, как оказалось, более важный вопрос.
В общем я недавно начал изучать C++ и поимел проблемы с кодировками, помогите мне перегрузить `<<` у `std::cout` чтобы он принимал строки в utf-8 а выводил в windows-866.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал следующее: (1) если у вас Unicode-строки (а так и должно быть в подавляющем большинстве случаев), использовать `std::wstring` и соответственно `std::wcout`. (2) временно переключить консоль из режима cp866 в режим utf-8 или utf-16: [SetConsoleOutputCP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1371069/276994).

Comment: Насколько я помню, товарищ использует MinGW, а того большие проблемы с локалями. Так что сомневаюсь, что `wstring` поможет.

Comment: да у меня MinGW

Answer (score 5):

Собственно, перегрузить сможете, только если будете передавать какой-то тип, отличный от string, char* и пр., поскольку << у cout уже перегружен для них. Можно просто создать функцию с такой вот примерно сигнатурой

```
 void printunicode (ostream&, const string&)
```

В ней собственно переводите юникодное содержимое строки в нужную кодировку, записываете его в буфер, а его уже передаете потоку.

Или даже проще. Создаете функцию, которая принимает строку с юникодом, а возвращает в нужной кодировке. Тогда можете ее использовать в череде операторов <<.

Comment: IMHO больше подходит именно второе (прием в юникоде (или указанной кодировке), а вывод в заданной кодировке)

Естественно, при цепочке вызовов, возникает проблема с буферами для перекодированной строки. В принципе она решаема, но всегда с теми или иными "подводными камнями".

Comment: ..сейчас попробую. Я ТОЛЬКО НАЧАЛ ИЗУЧАТЬ C++ ,конечно лучше бы было если бы Вы привели рабочий вариант , но всё равно спасибо :)

Comment: блин всё уже перепробовал лучший вариант преобразование файла исходника в windows-866 перед компиляцией

Comment: @Rules: а может, всё же попробуете wstring и SetConsoleOutputCP? Вот вам немного информации к размышлению:

* http://hashcode.ru/questions/179591
* http://forum.oszone.net/thread-129824-8.html
* http://stackoverflow.com/q/10882277/276994

Comment: А они же не подходят для обучения типа сколько символов столько размер присвоения номеров символов и тд

Comment: Если только приступил к изучение С++, то лучше пока со всеми этими кодировками даже не заморачиваться. Займись другими, более важными и принципиальными вещами. Может, даже лучше поставить в виртуальную машину убунту и работать на ней. Там нормальный полноценный gcc и все такое. На определенном этапе попробуй реализовать функцию "с нуля", как я написал, которая просто переводит из одной кодировки в другую: читает входную последовательность байтов, определяет, какой символ очередной и записывает его в соответственной кодировке в выходной буфер байтов.

Comment: @mikillskegg

   попробуй реализовать функцию "с нуля", как я написал, которая просто переводит из одной кодировки в другую: читает входную последовательность байтов, определяет, какой символ очередной и записывает его в соответственной кодировке в выходной буфер байтов.

А чем же iconv-то не устраивает?

Comment: А он в MinGW есть? Если есть, можно попробовать.

Comment: Они суть части одного проекта -- gnu от FSF.

Comment: @alexlz, у меня в MinGW iconv-a нет. 

И не уверен, что в любой **русской** винде его *легко* можно  заставить работать.

Comment: @avp не пойму без перевода.

Правда сам как-то с такой проблемой не сталкивался, но vim'у виндовому dll'ку подсовывал в начале 2000х. И, кстати, что за зверь **русская** винда?

Comment: @alexlz, **русская** винда, это обычно неизвестно-точно-какой пиратский дистрибутив, как-получилось-так-и-работает.

А главное для нее, чтобы оффис, браузер и игрушки работали.

Answer (score 1):

Помню как заминусовали когда в прошлый раз ответил на свой вопрос но всё таки отвечу :)
Понял что легче всего сменить кодировку файла на целевую (хорошо что я не японец :) ).
В общем для Code::Blocks сделал так:
1) Скачал uniconv.exe (давно качал счас не помню где)
1a) Т.к. uniconv не поддерживает utf-8 поставил по умолчанию в code::blocks windows-1251
2) Добавил в Tools такой Tool:
[image: screen shoot окна Edit tool]
3) И если работаю с `D:\ProjectsC++\C++ Learning\Chapter 2\Homework\Ch2_Ex1.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   using namespace std;
   cout << "Привет! " << endl << "Моё имя: Иван."
   << endl << "Моя фамилия: Черновалов.";
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

и вызываю tools=>reCHARSET WD то получаю `D:\ProjectsC++\C++ Learning\Chapter 2\Homework\Ch2_Ex1.cpp.cpp` в windows 866 затем вручную :( открываю его и вижу:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   using namespace std;
   cout << "ЏаЁўҐв! " << endl << "Њ®с Ё¬п: €ў ­."
   << endl << "Њ®п д ¬Ё«Ёп: —Ґа­®ў «®ў.";
   cin.get();
   return 0;
}
```

4) Строю&Запускаю и ву-аля:

[image: screen shoot запущенной программы]

Может кому поможет...

***PS:*** Как видите не могу получить (не создав Project) отдельно имя файла отдельно директорию поэтому приходится использовать двойное расширение чтобы отличать файлы (т.к ели изменять редактируемый файл то ошибка приложения) и приходится вручную открывать файл.
Ещё в code::blocks есть Tools+ и Scripts но я не умею ими пользоваться если кто может помогите усовершенствовать мой "костыль" :) чтобы создавался временный файл компилировался с именем текущего и удалялся...